# Kubernetes creating rc with local image

Tags: kubernetes

Im trying to create a replication Controller based on an image that I created locally. But when I try to create the rc it gives error `ImagePullBackOff`. I have created a cluster locally using `minikube`

Here is my `.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: ayonAppserver
  template:
    metadata:
      name: example.com
      labels:
        app: ayonAppserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: something
        image: nktest:10
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1024Mi
```

Command that I run to create the rc:

```
kubectl create -f <file>
```

When Im running `docker images` I see the image in the list

```
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID                CREATED             SIZE
nktest                    10                  e60b3c9c3bc6        10 hours ago        425 MB
```

when I run `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME            READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
example-gr9v2   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          2m
```

I have tried to run the docker image locally, and it runs fine

```
docker run -d --name="testAyonApp1" nktest:10
```

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: can you push the image to hub.docker.com? Otherwise, how kubernetes nodes know where to pull the image?

Comment: I was able to run it after pushing it to dockerhub but is there a way I can do this by just having the image locally created? changing my question to add that point  as well

Comment: If not hub.docker.com, then you need a private registry server to save your images that nodes can download from it. Otherwise, how nodes know where to download it? the image built locally is not accessible by nodes.

Comment: Thanks @BMW I just realized yes youre right. I was thinking that since the nodes are created locally by minukube they will be able to see the local images. Thats where I made the mistake the images has to be present inside the `node` instead of my local machine to be visible by k8s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to @BMW for helping me with the issue. The problem was that I was thinking since I created the cluster using `minikube` (locally) every image that I create in my local machine will be visible to minikube cluster. But an image is visible only when its present inside the node. Thats why every time I wanted to build it, it was looking for downloading the image.

I have now created a dockerhub account and pushed the image in the hub. And now things are working just fine.

Comment: You can also build the image on the docker daemon within the minikube VM.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan, can you give a little more clue on how to do that?